# wix burn custom bootstrapper - custom compiler extension

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

I have a custom bootstrapper using burn, in which I have to detect the driver version of a specific printer on startup and store this value in a burn variable for later usage. Until now, I did this in the overriden `Run` method of `BootstrapperApplication`, but I would rather create a `WixExtension`, to be able to do something like this:

```
<customUtil:PrinterDriverVersion PrinterName="somePrinter"
                                 Variable="variableToStoreVersionValue" />
```

This would be similar to the `RegistrySearch` element in wix's `UtilExtension`.

There is an example of a `CompilerExtension` in the book "WiX 3.6: A Developer's Guide To Windows Installer XML", but I don't get it. Why do I need a new msi table? I just want to use that in burn, not in an msi installer?

I looked at the source code of wix, trying to understand, how the `RegistrySearch` element works. So `UtilCompiler` just parses the xml attributes and then creates some rows in the `WixRegistrySearch` table. This table gets iterated by the binder, who writes all searches in the `BurnManifest` and then creates the resulting output file (.exe). But when and where do this searches get executed at runtime?

Is a `CompilerExtension` capable to get my task done, or am I on the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiX doesn't have this functionality today. This use case is also needed for the VSExtension to support installing VSIX packages into VS2017 with a bundle, since code needs to be executed to detect VS2017 instances. I created a feature request [here](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5539).

The UtilExtension searches are special. As you said, they end up in the BurnManifest. The code that executes the searches is in the [Burn engine](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix4/blob/develop/src/burn/engine/search.cpp).